# I cant align two input next to each other in Chrome, not in the same line

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

```
<div id="row2">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
</div>

input
{
    float: left;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #E4E2D6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #DDDBCF #EAE9E0 #E2E0D4 #DDDBCF;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: #959494;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 1%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 48%;
}
```

Updated the same in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/SKs89/3/)

this works well with firefox... but with chrome, it goes to new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box

Answer (score 1):

you have give styles for `mozilla` but haven't for `chrome`

This is  working fine in `chrome` now.

```
input
{
    float: left;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #E4E2D6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #DDDBCF #EAE9E0 #E2E0D4 #DDDBCF;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: #959494;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 1%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 48%;
}
```

Updated the same in fiddle. [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/SKs89/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the padding doesn't expand the box beyond the 100% you've done with the width and paddings.  With the conventional box model padding is added to the width rather than incorporated into it.  With "border-box" this is remedied and is supported in all modern browsers and IE8+ and can be polyfilled for older IEs.

You needn't add the vendor prefixes any more but I've added the webkit one that you were missing below.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this
**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SKs89/2/)**

**css**

```
input
{
    float: left;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #E4E2D6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #DDDBCF #EAE9E0 #E2E0D4 #DDDBCF;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: #959494;
    font-family: georgia;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 1%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width:47%;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box
float: left;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: #E4E2D6;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-color: #DDDBCF #EAE9E0 #E2E0D4 #DDDBCF;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
color: #959494;
font-family: georgia;
font-size: 1.6em;
height: 40px;
margin: 1%;
padding-left: 10px;
width: 48%;
```